# Java send sec commands

Tags: java, embedded, embedded-linux, java-8

I have a question.
I am trying to send cec codes from my raspberry pi to the TV, but i have a problem.
I am using java to send the commands, but nothing works.

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo \"standby 0000\" | cec-client -d 1 -s \"standby 0\" RPI");
```

But that does't work.
Does someone have a tip to send cec codes through java?

Comment: You could try asking this on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Connecting two commands via pipe is a shell feature which is not available when using the API for launching a single command. On the other hand it’s obsolete here. Just launch `cec-client` and write the `standby 0000` string into its stdin rather than using `echo`.